# Where can i find the stylesheets of google chrome's UI?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, stylesheet

I'm looking for the **master stylesheet of google chrome's UI** (windows: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome - ? ). Where can I find it or doesn't it exists?

regards, msec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebKit's (and therefore Chromium's) default stylesheet is in the WebKit source tree at [`/Source/WebCore/css/html.css`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/html.css), but I don't believe it's accessible from the filesystem for a particular profile; it's baked into the application itself.

What's the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: thank you Mike - I thought as much, however I want to learn new tricks and prepare my skills. regards!